# Combinations of a string with specific variable characters

Tags: python, string

How can I collect the combinations of a string, in which certain characters (but not all) are variable?

In other words, I have an input string and a character map. The character map specifies which characters are variable, and what they could be replaced with. The function then yields all possible combinations.

To put this in context, I'm trying to collect possible variations for an OCR output string that could have been misinterpreted by the OCR engine.

Example input:

```
"ABCD"
```

Example character map:

```
dict(
    B=("X", "Z"),
    D=("E")
)
```

Intended output:

```
[
    "ABCD",
    "ABCE",
    "AXCD",
    "AXCE",
    "AZCD",
    "AZCE"
]
```

Comment: What about `"AABBCCD0"` ?

Comment: That one too -- my bad.

Comment: Can somebody explain why the question is too broad? Are there no functions similar to `combinations` that would pull this trick off with a few additions?

Comment: @Robbert please edit to clarify the question so I can vote to reopen -- there's an excellent underlying Q and I'm rarin' to post it but it needs to be expressed better, according to the "vigilantes" that just closed your Q!

Comment: @Robbert no there's no pre-made function in the stdlib, but one **can** be made e.g by recursive backtracking and it's in fact an interesting problem.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've just revised the question a bit -- will this suffice? My headache agrees it is an interesting problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is too broad either. Seems like a well defined problem. 

Maybe you need to add some code to show what you have tried to do so far?

Comment: This may be useful http://www.norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> s = "ABCD"
>>> d = {"B": ["X", "Z"], "D": ["E"]}
>>> poss = [[c]+d.get(c,[]) for c in s]
>>> poss
[['A'], ['B', 'X', 'Z'], ['C'], ['D', 'E']]
>>> [''.join(p) for p in product(*poss)]
['ABCD', 'ABCE', 'AXCD', 'AXCE', 'AZCD', 'AZCE']
```

Note that I made `d["D"]` a list rather than simply a string for consistency.

Comment: This is crazy. I certainly did not expect this to be solved in merely two lines (see how I solved it in the first place below).

Comment: `product` is a very nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was very ugly and non-Pythonic, but here goes:

```
def fuzzy_search(string, character_map):
    all_variations = []

    for i, character in enumerate(string):
        if character in character_map:
            character_variations = list(character_map[character])
            character_variations.insert(0, character)

            if i == len(string) - 1:
                return [string[:-1] + variation for variation in character_variations]

            for variation in character_variations:
                sub_variations = fuzzy_search(string[i + 1:], character_map)

                for sub_variation in sub_variations:
                    all_variations.append(string[:i] + variation + sub_variation)

            return all_variations

    return all_variations

map = dict(
    B=("X", "Z"),
    D=("E")
)

print fuzzy_search("ABCD", map)
```

Outputs:

```
['ABCD', 'ABCE', 'AXCD', 'AXCE', 'AZCD', 'AZCE']
```

I figured there should be way more elegant solutions than a recursive function with multiple loops.