# Append to Python list all possible transformations for each list item

Tags: python, list

I have a list of possible passwords, and I need to append simple transformations of each password in this list. Say my list is

```
['sauce', 'banana']
```

and I have a series of transformations shown here.

'a'-->'@'

's'-->'$'

I then want to add to the list every possible transformation. So now the list should look something like

```
['$auce', 's@uce', '$@uce', 'b@nana', 'ban@na',
 'banan@', 'b@n@na', 'b@nan@,' 'ban@n@', 'b@n@n@']
```

How would I do that in Python?

I tried first creating a function that made all transformations. Then I took that transformed string and essentially did a cross product with the original string. However, this causes a lot of repeats, and it seems a bit hacky.

The function:

```
def symbolize(s):
    options = {
        'a': '@',
        'S': '$'
    }
    copy = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] in options:
            copy += options[s[i]]
        else:
            copy += s[i]
    return copy
```

And then the cross product:

```
for x in range(len(candidates)):
    candidates += list(''.join(t) for t in itertools.product(
        *zip(candidates[x], symbolize(candidates[x]))))
```

Comment: If you're struggling to get started, try to solve this problem for a single password. If that's still too hard, just try to solve it first for a single letter.

Comment: If you don't want repeats, use sets.  set([a,a])==set([a]).

Comment: I think you could simply modify the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986559/combinations-of-a-string-with-specific-variable-characters/27988133#27988133) using `itertools.product` and throw away the first element (which is the no-replacement case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

def all_versions_of_word(word, alt_chars, skip_orig=True):
    chars = [ch + alt_chars.get(ch, "") for ch in word]
    combos = product(*chars)
    if skip_orig and word: next(combos)  # drop the first item
    return ("".join(c) for c in combos)

def transform_passwords(passwords, alt_chars={"a":"@", "s":"$"}):
    for word in passwords:
        yield from all_versions_of_word(word, alt_chars)
```

which runs like

```
>>> list(transform_passwords(['sauce', 'banana']))
['s@uce',
 '$auce',
 '$@uce',
 'banan@',
 'ban@na',
 'ban@n@',
 'b@nana',
 'b@nan@',
 'b@n@na',
 'b@n@n@']
```

Comment: I got an invalid syntax error on `from` in `transform_passwords`

Comment: @alexjp: `yield from` is relatively new syntax (Python 3.3+); for lower versions of Python you can instead do `for version in all_versions_of_word(word, alt_chars): yield version`. It does exactly the same thing, it's just a bit wordier.

Comment: I found a bug in this. If alt_chars maps a specific character to two different things (e.g., 'S' -> '$' and 'S' -> '5') then only the one specified later in alt_chars will be used. It would be nice if it could handle multiple possible mappings for a single character.

Comment: @alexjp: try `'s':'$5'` instead. A dict cannot map a key to two values, so I packed the alternate values into a string. It's not a bug, you're just using it wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can use recursion, although python limits it to a depth of 2000:

Create a mapping and the list:

```
lst = ['sauce', 'banana']
mapping = {'a':'@', 's':'$'}
```

Now recursively generate all possibilities (including no replacement at all):

```
def opts(_mapping, _str):
    if not _str:
       yield ""
    else:
        for opt in opts(_mapping, _str[1:]):
            if _str[0] in _mapping:
                yield _mapping[_str[0]] + opt
            yield _str[0] + opt
```

Output:

```
[list(opts(mapping, st)) for st in lst]

=> [['$@uce', 's@uce', '$auce', 'sauce'], ['b@n@n@', 'ban@n@', 'b@nan@', 'banan@', 'b@n@na', 'ban@na', 'b@nana', 'banana']]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the underscores before the variable names?

Comment: 1. to prevent overriding Python's built-in `str`. 2. to prevent overriding variables from outer context.

Answer (score 0):

I really had fun digging into this answer! There's a lot of iterating over the string here, but I like my answer!

```
import functools

def transform(pwd, subs):
    result = {pwd}
    stack = [pwd]
    # contains all resolved strings left to permute on
    while True:
        pwd = stack.pop()
        # grab a password

        if not stack and not any(i in subs for i in pwd):
            return result
            # if the stack is empty and is no way to permute further,
            #  then return our result.

        for idx,ch in enumerate(pwd):
            if ch in subs:
                repl = subs[ch]
                transformation = pwd[:idx]+repl+pwd[idx+1:]
                # transformation is our transformed word
                result.add(transformation)
                # add our transformation to our result set
                stack.append(transformation)
                # and toss it on our stack to transform further

def transform_multiple(pwds, subs):
    return functools.reduce(set.union,
                            (transform(pwd, subs) for pwd in pwds))
```

DEMO:

```
In [55]: transform_multiple(['banana', 'sauce','ananas'], {'a':'@', 's':'$'})
Out[55]:
{'$@uce',
 '$auce',
 '@n@n@$',
 '@n@n@s',
 '@n@na$',
 '@n@nas',
 '@nan@$',
 '@nan@s',
 '@nana$',
 '@nanas',
 'an@n@$',
 'an@n@s',
 'an@na$',
 'an@nas',
 'anan@$',
 'anan@s',
 'anana$',
 'ananas',
 'b@n@n@',
 'b@n@na',
 'b@nan@',
 'b@nana',
 'ban@n@',
 'ban@na',
 'banan@',
 'banana',
 's@uce',
 'sauce'}
```

If I were to spend a little more time on this, I'd probably remove the `if not stack and not any(...)` call and put a flag inside the `for idx,ch in enumerate` loop that flags if there's a change made to that string, then test `if not flag and not stack: return result` after the loop ends. This would save us a whole iteration on `pwd` and `len(pwd)` membership tests every time through the loop.